# Create a gradient around the edges of a hexagonal grid?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of hexagons that I want to add a background to it like the image below:
[image]

I'm not sure how to make that gradient except by using a linear gradient but that does not work very well.
Another problem is I want the gradient to stop at the edges of the hexagons which it doesn't the way I am doing it.

Here is the code I currently have:

```css
.background-hexagon-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#915023, transparent);

}

.background-hexagon-row {
    margin-top: -15px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.background-hexagon {
    background-color: #222222;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 57.5px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);

}
```

```html
<div class="background-hexagon-container left">
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need the hexagon shape to be divs or the whole can be made using only gradient?

Comment: I dont need them to be divs thats just how i thought to do it, as long as it looks like the picture it doesnt matter because it will just be a background element

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry if I'm bothering you, I don't know if you saw my last message because I forgot to @ you.

Comment: @hbblue For performance reason, I would create 2 backgrounds, one, linear-gradient, and over the gradient, I would put a background image on repeat, for the image Google for "hexagon repeating tile pattern" and use something from there, just make sure, that the image is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your background property like in the exemple bellow :

```css
.background-hexagon-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    
    position: absolute;
   //background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(145, 80, 35, .6), rgba(145, 80, 35, 1), #000);

}

.background-hexagon-row {
    margin-top: -15px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.background-hexagon {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 57.5px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
     background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(145, 80, 35, .6), rgba(145, 80, 35, 1), #000);    

}

.background-hexagon::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #222;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 57.5px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-hexagon-container left">
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-hexagon-row">
        <div class="background-hexagon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to make this background only go arround the hexagons and not fill the entire square?

Comment: You are asking to different question I guess better to make two different post. Anyway I've edited the code to let you see what trix you could using the way you did to manage that. After it is maybe better to try another way if you want exactly the same result as before

Answer (score 0):

You can add gradients to borders using `border-image` CSS property. Since **gradients are images** in CSS, you can use them as values for `border-image`.
For example, I have used them [here](https://dev.to/jashgopani/windows-10-button-hover-effect-using-css-and-vanilla-js-1io4) on button.
For reference, you can refer [MDN CSS Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) and playground with the official [border-image generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator)